# How to train a volume (3D tensor) with Pytorch for a GAN?

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

Good evening!

For backround:
For university, i am trying to reproduce a CryoGAN network (CryoEM with a GAN).
The goal is to reproduce the 3D structure of a protein; The given data are projection images from the real protein. For CryoGAN, the generator does not consist of a neural network per se, but of a volume (for the protein) and a physics simulator, which creates 2D projections of the 3d volume. The physics simulator is a working program, so the only thing I want to train is the volume itself.
The volume is a 3D tensor of 128x128x128 voxels.

My idea was, to create a tensor for the volume, and use this as the parameters to learn. The code runs through, but the volume does not update :(
Do you happen to have any ideas? I appended the relevant lines below.
Thanks in advance!

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.gen = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(128, 128, 128))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.gen(x)


gen = Generator(projection_pixels)


opt_gen = optim.Adam(gen.parameters(), lr=lr)
loss_criterion = nn.BCELoss()



#...feeding discriminator with projections from fake and real protein, calculating loss for generator



gen.zero_grad()
lossG.backward()
opt_gen.step()
```

I already tried changing the initialization of the volume to
`self.gen = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(128,128,128).uniform_())`
But that did no change anything.